# Follow up with command, using the next variable in an external *.txt file

Tags: batch-file, command, batch-processing

I would like to access an *.txt from an batch file. Inside the *.txt are numbers, row by row. The batch should take this numbers and parse them into a variable to execute an command.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%x in (kbupdate.txt) do set Build=%%x

wusa.exe /KB:%Build% /uninstall /quiet /norestart

@echo off
echo  KB %Build% has been uninstalled.
```

Those script works perfectly for the first entry in the *.txt file. But not for the others. Therefore i configured an loop- and i'm stuck there now:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%x in (kbupdate.txt) do set Build=%%x

:wusa
wusa.exe /KB:%Build% /uninstall /quiet /norestart

goto wusa

@echo off
echo  KB %Build% has been uninstalled.
```

The loop still catches the first entry and repeats it. What am I doing wrong here? I would like to force the script to check the first entry of the *.txt and perform then

```
wusa.exe /KB:%Build% /uninstall /quiet /norestart
```

Then doing the same command with the second line in the *.txt and so on until all lines are finished?

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Best, Nino

Answer (score 0):

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (kbupdate.txt) do (
 for %%y in (%%x) do (
  wusa.exe /KB:%%y /uninstall /quiet /norestart
  echo  KB %%y has been uninstalled.
 )
)
```

each line of the file is applied to `%%x` in turn.

the `for` in the next line sees

```
1,2,3,4
```

(as read into `%%x`) and applies each comma-separated value (could also be space-separated if you like) to `%%y` which will thus get `1`  `2`  `3`  `4`

Then simply use `%%y` in place of `%build%`